# How open search window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, find window will open in browser. How Can I open that same window on html button click event using javascript code. I tried with window.find() but it will not work.

[image: Find window]?

Comment: Google Search API provides explicit search for your site content.. It might be the closest possible alternative..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot. Browsers provide no API that will do that.

The closest you could come would be to implement your own "search this page" widget and backend from scratch in JS. It almost certainly isn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

[`window.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.find) has a specific flag `aShowDialog`. If it set true - dialog will show, but because this method is not a part of any standard it works only in Firefox(it's Gecko feature):

```
window.find("Home", false, false, false, true, false, true)
```

Thanks to @Quentin:

> There are [plans](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395) to remove it from Firefox

Comment: And there are plans to remove it from Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395